# Error can not multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, numpy

I was following a tutorial online on transfer learning and I faced this problem:
Here is the code:

```
train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_train.npy', 'rb'))
train_labels = np.array(
    [0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))

validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_features_validation.npy'))
validation_labels = np.array(
    [0] * (nb_validation_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples / 2))
```

and I get this error :

```
[0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))
can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: [0] is a list.  [0]*4 produces [0,0,0,0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `[0]` and `[1]` are lists. The multiplication operator for lists is to repeat it and is only possible when multiplied by an integer. So `[1]*2==[1,1]`. If this is the desired outcome, then you have to just simply cast `int` on them:
`[0] * int(nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * int(nb_train_samples / 2))`